# "Rubber band" events on phonegap app

Tags: ios, cordova, rubber-band

I'm working on an iOS app using Phonegap/ Cordova and jQuery Mobile.

I want to be able to refresh the data when the user pulls the page down (rubber band effect). I tried using iScroll 4 but it made scrolling my page slow.

I didn't find a phonegap plugin for this. I thought this was a pretty standard iOS feature so maybe I am missing something? Is there any easy way to listen to the pull down event using phonegap / cordova?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line into **CDVViewController.m** (*Cordova 2.0* or later) is said to work but I've actually never tried it myself as I'm still using iScroll 4. Give it a shot and let me know how it worked for you.

```
[webView.scrollView setDecelerationRate:UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal];
```

Likewise, however somewhat irrelevant to this matter, the code snippet below is said to reduce the on click delay from 300 ms which is also something phonegap developers usually want. Neither this nor the line above has been properly tested but perhaps a good way to start off.

```
[webView.scrollView setDelaysContentTouches:NO];
```